# Enable bootstrap column backgrounds to bleed to edge of viewport

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to work out how to achieve the following in Bootstrap 3:

1. I have a HTML page which is primarily based around bootstrap's fixed container grid.
2. Half way down the page I want a row with columns of different sizes.
3. I want the content (text / images) inside these columns to line up with the content inside the columns in the fixed container grid.
4. I want the background colours of the left and right furthest columns to bleed right to the edge of the page.

It may help if I illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:
[image: Bootstrap column backgrounds bleeding to edge of viewport]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**Update:** as requested here's some code examples of what I currently have: http://www.bootply.com/ZzOefJGRRq As you can see the text and columns in the fluid container are not lining up correctly.

Comment: you need to make a `container-fluid` parent `div` and set a `background`.

Comment: add your `code` or make a `snippet` so we can help you.

Comment: @mmativ updated with code.

Comment: `light-gray` on left and `gray` on right?

Comment: @mmativ Yes. I can do it with a single colour across all columns no problem. I can't get it to work when I have different colours for different size columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `:before` elements and some classes

https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/wa8myL9v/2/

```
.bg:before {position:absolute;left:0em; content:'';height:100%;width:800em;z-index:-1}
```

**UPDATE**

added media query for small devices
https://jsfiddle.net/ex3ntia/wa8myL9v/3/

**UPDATE 2**

I have added the following line to fix the big horizontal scroll on chrome browsers.

```
body, html {overflow-x: hidden;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
```

Comment: Explain reason of -1 or avoid useless actions

Comment: Fine, no problem. You can usually use :before and :after elements to archieve "out of the line" effects.

Comment: I'm seeing a huge horizontal scrollbar which goes across 800em of green bar when I view it in Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 m (64-bit), otherwise this was just what I was looking for!

Comment: See my answer below to resolve overflow issues using width: 50vw

Answer (score 6):

## Bootstrap 4

Use position absolute before or after elements with width: 50vw

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/garethdweaver/pen/JVezVw)

### HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 c-col-bg--red">
      ...
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 c-col-bg--blue">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.container-fluid {
    max-width: 1000px;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    div[class*="c-col-bg"] {
        position: relative;
    }

    div[class*="c-col-bg"]:after {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        width: 50vw;
    }

    .c-col-bg--red:after {
        right: 0;
        background: red;
    }

    .c-col-bg--blue:after {
        left: 0;
        background: blue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; no framework has this out of the box, because covering all possible use cases is both very complex and would result in a huge amount of code.

It is doable but requires some amount of manual coding. The approach below works for 2 columns. More columns and breakpoints will require a more complex solution.

Sample markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">default column</div>
    <div class="col-7">default column</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container container--fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">fluid column, aligned with above</div>
    <div class="col-7">fluid column, aligned with above</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container container--bleed">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-5">
      <div class="content">like fluid, but content is aligned with default</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-7">
      <div class="content">like fluid, but content is aligned with default</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

scss for brevity

```
  // assuming you have these values or able to set them
  $max-width: 1140px;
  $gutter: 8px;
  $grid: 12;
  $customColumns: [5, 7]; // columns you want to align

  // sample grid
  .container {
    max-width: $max-width;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-left: $gutter;
    padding-right: $gutter;
  }
  .row {
    display: flex;
    margin-left: -$gutter;
    margin-right: -$gutter;
  }
  div[class^='col'] {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: $gutter;
    padding-right: $gutter;
    position: relative;
  }
  @for $i from 1 through $grid {
    .col-#{$i} {
      width: calc(100% * #{$i} / #{$grid});
    }
  }
  .container--bleed, .container--fluid {
    max-width: none;
  }
  
  // custom grid rules for alignment
  @media(min-width: #{$max-width}) {
    @each $i in $customColumns {
      .container--bleed, .container--fluid {
        .col-#{$i}:first-child, .col-#{$i}:last-child {
          width: calc(#{$max-width * $i / $grid} + ((100% - #{$max-width}) / 2));
        }
      }
      .container--bleed {
        .col-#{$i}:first-child { 
          padding-left: calc((100% - #{$max-width}) / 2 + #{$gutter});
        }
        .col-#{$i}:last-child { 
          padding-right: calc((100% - #{$max-width}) / 2 + #{$gutter});
        }
      }    
    }
  }
```

I created a codepen POC for a similar layout here: https://codepen.io/bariscc/pen/BajKpMP

Answer (score -1):

You can implement the `container-fluid` to achieve this.

Basically your webpage will have the following structure:

```
<div class="container">
   <p>Content here</p>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <p>"Bleeded" content here</p>
</div>
<div class="container">
   <p>And it continues with the fixed width!</p>
</div>
```

If you need to adjust the spaces between those containers, you can add your own classes or ID:s to each and kind of take it from there. Since containers in Bootstrap don't have much of a default styling, this is very efficient way of creating what you're looking to do in here.

**EDIT:** After inspecting the comments section and looking at the code you provided, I assume you want to have the fluid container, but keep the contents within it lined up with the fixed container, right?

For this, you can just put another `<div class="container">...</div>` in your `container-fluid`. Check the [updated fiddle](http://www.bootply.com/LdL4q07iEf).

Comment: I think this does not meet 
"3) I want the content (text / images) inside these columns to line up with the content inside the columns in the fixed container grid."

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't solve the issue. The colour that bleeds to the edge needs to be the same as each column that makes up the beginning and end of the row. You've simply added a single colour that spans the entire row underneath them both.

Answer (score -1):

Where you have the special row, you need a div with container-fluid class encapsulating a div with container class (this is a fixed width class).

Then you need to account for the background colours either side.  Either add additional divs within container-fluid each side of container and set background colour, or perhaps use a three column table.

Comment: You should provide a code example of this. And using tables in responsive websites is just pointless when building the page layout. Background coloring can easily be achieved by using gradients as well, though you'd have to manage them a bit in different viewports.