# two-column footer with fluid backgrounds using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to build two-column footer with fluid backgrounds using bootstrap grid system, see the example below. The content inside these columns should not be fluid. It also should be responsive and stack on small devices.

Is this possible?

Here's what I did for now, but as i said the content should not be fluid, how do I achieve this?

```css
.footer .row {
  height: 100px;
  color: white;
}

.left {
  background-color: #222;
}

.right {
  background-color: #333
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-5 left">
        Left
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-7 right">
        Right
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Link to pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRwMdJ)

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dqyhj.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, your question should contain a [**Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What have you tried? And yes, it's possible. Have you read the documentation for Bootstrap? The [**answer to your question**](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) is there.

Comment: Thank your for your answer, i have edited the question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55654361/2466932

Answer (score 0):

## HTML:

```
<footer>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="footer-col-rt col-md-6">
                ....
            </div>
            <div class="footer-col-lf col-md-6">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

### CSS:

```
footer .footer-col-rt {
   background-color: #233140;
}
footer .footer-col-lf {
   background-color: #2C3E50;
}
```

Comment: This is the exact same code I have for now. The problem is the content inside these columns is also fluid, but it should have max width like the rest of the content on the site. I have edited my question.