# Bootstrap 3 - align area to a column inside .container, size to edge of view port

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

Got a design request that I just cannot for the life of me work out. Consider this image showing the bootstrap grid with a 12-column layout:

[image: Annotated bootstrap grid]

The 3 black rectangles represent:

1. A column of padding
2. Main content area
3. Interactive map

Section `3` is the problem; it needs to be perfectly alligned to the grid system inside the `.container`, and also go right up to the edge of the screen *without overflowing*. As sections `1` + `2` don't add up to 6 columns, I'm having a hard time sizing section `3`.

I haven't managed to come up with any viable solution- the closest (which is still pretty far) is to [make use of pseudo-elements on the grid system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37986953/4027341) - the only problem with that is it's not possible to put the map inside a pseudo-element.

Please note I already have a JavaScipt solution in place for the time being, I am looking for a CSS/HTML only solution to reduce flickering on page load.

---

As has been requested, here are some images that I hope will make the request clearer.

Before - there's a gap between the map and the edge of the viewport:
[image]

After - map is aligned to fixed-width bootstrap grid and the edge of the viewport:
[image]

---

Some pseudocode

```
<div class="section left-content side-map">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
            Content - remain unchanged
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-offset-1">
            <div id="contact-map">
                Map here - need to extend to viewport edge
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: provide what you have tried..

Comment: Also that picture does not make the question clear at all. Add a current and desired result into the question to make it alot clearer. Also some code would be helpfull.

Comment: @Jana My problem is that I simply cannot think of a solution that does not have glaring problems. The fact that I need it to not overflow means that an excessively wide element with a top-level element with `width: 100%;overflow: hidden;` is out of the picture, and I can't manually increase the width as I'd need a media query for every single pixel. There's no code posted because I'm at a loss for where to begin and cannot find a similar enough question

Comment: @Granny See edit

Comment: @Scoots I might be as blind as a bat but i do not see a difference between picture 1 and picture 2 of the result.

Comment: @Granny see the right-hand margin next to the map. In the first it is constrained to the Bootstrap grid. In the second it extends to the browser viewport edge.

Comment: @Scoots Try this in your css. If i understood the problem correctly, this should fix it: html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

Comment: @Scoots..I got your problem..But viewing code is better for easy solution

Comment: @Scoots As Jana said, its hard troubleshooting this without some code.

Comment: @Scoot just remove `position:absolute` i think that gets stuck

Comment: @Jana See the edit

Comment: @Granny It's not a problem with body/html margin/padding. It's a problem with needing to align something to the bootstrap grid system *and* the browser viewport. That margin at the side is brought about because `.container` is a fixed-width element that jumps down in width at various breakpoints.

Comment: Am I missing something here? `.col-sx-8` (page) + `.col-sx-4` (map) ?

Comment: @ProEvilz Which will leave a gap between the side of the map and the side of the viewport. Which is exactly what I'm trying to eliminate.

Comment: Which is caused by margin/padding. Just delete it?

Comment: @Scoots Like i said its hard to troubleshoot without the actual code.

Comment: @ProEvilz The element needs to be constrained to the bootstrap grid. Sure I can take the element out of the bootstrap grid to align the right edge of the map to the browser viewport, but then how do I align the left edge of the map to the bootstrap grid?

Comment: Why would it not be constrained to the grid if you remove padding?

Comment: @Granny The code posted is pretty much the actual code. Everything else is just fluff. I'm not asking for help fixing the code - I'm asking for help achieving a concept.

Comment: @Scoots See this pen. https://codepen.io/ash94/pen/gXzOrd?editors=1100 Is that not what you want?

Comment: @ProEvilz It assumes a full-width design for the rest of the site. This page just features the designer for this client being a bit nutty. The design was agreed without my input, but I still need to honour it. Everything needs to be constrained to the grid within `.container` (not `.container-fluid`!). The map needs to be aligned to that grid - but also extend to the viewport edge.

Comment: So in short, you want whats in the pen, but using a fixed with container?

Comment: @ProEvilz Pretty much

Comment: Hmm.. I see the issue. Are you sure you're not able to use `.container-fluid`? I mean just for this *one* section on the page. You don't have to wrap everything in one main container. You could cut the main container off mid page, open a new fluid one, put this map and stuff in then close it off and re-open the initial container?

Comment: @ProEvilz Quite sure sadly - There's stuff further down the page the left edge of the map aligns to; a fact which the designer assures me is essential to the aesthetic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159577/discussion-between-proevilz-and-scoots).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another approach to solve this issue can be using CSS Grid Layout. In order to do this, you can change a markup of the section of your page: get rid of the Bootstrap's `.container` wrapper and replace the `.row` element with your own grid container, like the following HTML:

```
<div class="section left-content side-map">
  <div class="grid-row">
    <div class="content col">
      Content - remain unchanged
    </div>
    <div class="map-col">
      <!-- the map goes here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .grid-row {
    display: grid;
    /* create 14 columns: 12 build up the actual grid,
       two more columns emulate left/right "margins" */
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(12, 60px) 1fr;
  }

   .content {
    grid-column: 3 / span 7; /* span 7 columns starting from #2 (technically, the 3rd) */
  }

  .map-col {
    grid-column: 10 / span 5; /* span 5 last columns, including the right "margin" */
  }

}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .grid-row {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(12, 80px) 1fr;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .grid-row {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr repeat(12, 95px) 1fr;
  }
}
```

The key part of this solution is that "margins" that absorb the extra horizontal space outside the main 12 grid columns are also grid columns (with automatic width), and you can make your blocks span these extra columns just like any other, so the browser will do all the sizing math for you automatically.

You can see this approach in action in this fork of the Ilya Myasin's CodePen: https://codepen.io/SelenIT/pen/mjoomN?editors=1100. I also added the `-ms`-prefixed equivalents to CSS Grid properties there to make the demo work in IE10+ as well.

Comment: And that's perfect even with the vertical scrollbar, so it's pretty much a superior solution. The project for which this question was raised is well and truly out the door now, but I've had similar design features come through me since. I will bear this in mind for future cases - thank you for answering such an old question. As I mentioned earlier I feel this is the superior answer so I'm actually going to mark it accepted.

Answer (score 6):

Hope [this pen](https://codepen.io/dubrowsky/pen/JOvLYE?editors=1100) will help.

I've added negative right margin to the map column to compensate the variable container gap. It is calculated this way: `calc((100vw - @container)/2*-1)` (half of the difference between window width and container width) for each bootstrap breakpoint.

Unfortunately `100vw` includes scrollbar width, so if page content is higher than window height the annoying horizontal scrollbar appears. I've wrapped the container with `overflow-x:hidden;` div, so it just hides extra ~20px on the right side of the map. I suppose in your particular case it's ok because standard google map has enough space between it's right side and useful controls.

Comment: That is a pretty cool solution, +1. I'm going to hold out to the end of the bounty just in case someone can come up with something that doesn't have that little bit of overflow, but right now this is a solid answer

Comment: I know only one way to fix this overflow problem, and I used it in one of my projects, but it's not compatible with the way bootstrap adjusts container size. The idea is to use `margin-[left/right]: calc( (100vw - 1140px) / 2)` instead of bootstrap's `margin:auto; width:1140px;`. Then `margin-right: calc( (100vw - 1140px) / 2 * -1);` on the right column gives exactly what you need. But (on my Mac + Chrome) real container size becomes 1125px instead of 1140px and it doesn't match bootstrap's default grid.

Comment: Look at the last block on [this pen](https://codepen.io/dubrowsky/pen/WXyNEW?editors=1100). If you can override default sizing for all containers, it will solve the problem.

Comment: A bit of tweaking and that's workable. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

in bootstrap `container` has width in `px`....so give `.container` a width in `% or vw`

```
    .container{
      width: 80vw;
    }
or
    .container{
      width: 80%;
    }
```

Comment: The design I need to follow is a fixed-width. This does not solve the problem.

Comment: if u gonna use fixed width for container it ll create issue in responsive

Comment: Thats literally the purpose of bootstrap - using different break points you can say how many columns a cell occupies at different screen sizes. The container automatically scales down at these break points.

Answer (score -1):

Try It..You have to fix grid as 12 section `col-sm-12` before split that.. and remove `col-lg-offset-1` and remove `position:padding;`

```
<div class="section left-content side-map">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-7">
                Content - remain unchanged
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-3">
                <div id="contact-map">
                    Map here - need to extend to viewport edge
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This removes the padding added by `.container`, but does not compensate for the variable gap added between `.container` and the browser viewport edge.

Comment: you should have to give the gap between .container and the browser viewport edge...give padding to `.container`

Comment: But that gap is entirely variable, and is controlled entirely by the end user. I can compensate for it with JavaScript (as I have already done as a (hopefully) temporary solution) - but the only way to use CSS to give that gap would be to create an `@media screen and (max-width: 1234px) {}` rule for every single pixel - which is totally unrealistic.

Answer (score -1):

just add the padding-right:0; on the map side. 
don't use the col-lg-offset-1 for map increase the column from 3 to 4. This will resolve the problem

```
<div class="section left-content side-map">
    <div class="container" style="border:1px solid #ccc;">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8 col-lg-7 col-lg-offset-1">
            Content - remain unchanged
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 text-right" style="padding-right:0;">
            <div id="contact-map">
                Map here - need to extend to viewport edge
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no padding, `.container`is fixed a width element in bootstrap, this solution leaves the gab between `.container`and the vviewport edge

Comment: add the pull-right class instead of text-right and remove the pull-right class in small screen to the proper working
<div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 pull-right">
            <div id="contact-map">
                Map here - need to extend to viewport edge
            </div>
        </div>