# Stretch left side of image outside container to edge of the page

Tags: html, css

Normally I'm quite good at CSS but I cannot figure out how to do this particular layout.

I have a container with a maximum width of 1,400 pixels.  The left and right margin are set to `auto` so when the viewport is above 1,400 pixels the container is centralised.

I then have an image outside the container with a div next to it, the image occupying 40% of the viewport, the div taking up the remaining 60% of the viewport.

What I want, is a div inside the 60% portion, that doesn't go any wider than the right-hand edge of the 1,400 pixel container above.

A diagram might make things clearer:

[image]

My CSS so far:

```
div.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
}

div.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}

div.inner {
  ???
}
```

For `div.inner` I've tried variations of percentages and `calc` but to no avail. For clarification, everything on the layout is fine apart from the pink box which I cannot get to line up with the right-hand edge of the red box.

Comment: margin-right: calc( ( 100vw - 1400px ) / 2 );    ? Note that vw includes the scrollbar which might throw you off a bit.

Comment: I asked a very similar question a while ago - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47349180/bootstrap-3-align-area-to-a-column-inside-container-size-to-edge-of-view-por - you might find the answer I accepted useful. Just be careful of `width: 100vw` - for some reason I don't understand it includes the width of a vertical scrollbar.

Comment: If you want to keep it as width:   width: calc(60vw - ((100vw - 1400px) / 2));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since the red div has a max-width of `1400px` then the space left will be `100vw-1400px` so the space on one side will be the half. You can simply make the `padding-right` of the green box to be `(100vw - 1400px)/2` which is also `50vw - 700px`.

Here is an example where I consider 600px instead of 1400px:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  margin:0;
}

div.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
}

div.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  padding-right:calc(50vw - 300px);
  background:green;
}

div.inner {
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<img src="" ><div class="right">
<div class="inner">
</div>

</div>
```

You can also use it as `margin-right` of the inner div:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  margin:0;
}

div.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background:red;
  height:50px;
}

img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40%;
  height:50px;
  background:yellow;
}

div.right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
  background:green;
}

div.inner {
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  margin-right:calc(50vw - 300px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
</div>
<img src="" ><div class="right">
<div class="inner">
</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you,works well.  There is a slight discrepancy due to the scroll bar width, however for this particular application it doesn't matter