# How to create 2 column layout with second DIV with infinite width

Tags: css

How to create this kind of layout with CSS without complex use of position:absolute 
 (looking for simple methods). Consider also a "responsiveness" of the page.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: infinite = 100vw in this case

Comment: I suggest you to dive into flexbox.

Comment: You could use percentages on width with display: inline-block, for both elements

Comment: related, not the same but you can get some ideas :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50257456/stretch-left-side-of-image-outside-container-to-edge-of-the-page/50257633#50257633

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post for why Flexbox is the best: http://uidevdaily.com/2018/why-you-should-start-using-flexbox/. I made a Jsfiddle to answer your question: https://jsfiddle.net/q6ac134L/13/. Below is the CSS code:

```
div {
  height: 100vh;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
}

.col-1 {
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.col-2 {
  background-color: gray;
  flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is (which I did't explain well in the first post), that I have to center the layout (because this is the main page layout).  So the to columns divs needs a container with width and margin: 0 auto ... See link -> https://jsfiddle.net/q6ac134L/17/

Comment: If you need to set the fixed width as 800px for the container, it's going be 800px wide with 100px for the first column and the rest, which is 700px, for the second column. I think what you want is to center the content within the columns instead of setting the fixed width of the main container.