# (foundation) grid cell breakout with background image

Tags: css, grid, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I'm using foundation for my grid system but this could be a problem in any grid system. I got basicly 3 cells wrapped by one container but one of the cells should grow to the page border (left in my [**Sampe-Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qd94Z.gif)
but this also could be on the right side).

when I define a fixed width like in this fiddle, it works, but the background image too wide, I need a responsive version :-/

HTML:

```
<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="grid-x grid-margin-x">
    <div class="large-4 cell">
     <div class="specialdiv"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 cell">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
    <div class="large-4 cell">
      <p>test</p>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.specialdiv {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 100%;
}
.specialdiv:after {
        content: "";
        display: block;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 2000px;
        background: url("https://images.pexels.com/photos/531880/pexels-photo-531880.jpeg");
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZjeBOz

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what exactly you want, but if the goal is to keep the image in the cell with no regards to cropping you can just apply overflow-x: hidden; to  .specialdiv

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please check the sample-image I attached in my first post.
You can see the Image is not cropped, and the width of the image is the cell width + "X" pixels to the left. 
As I have a fixed container, but an unknown width of the global page, the fixed "width: 2000px;" from my code-sample doenst work here.

So maybe I need JS here like
"page.width - container.width + cell.width" 
or something like that. You know what I mean? ;-)

Comment: Found another post with the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985506/enable-bootstrap-column-backgrounds-to-bleed-to-edge-of-viewport  but I need an image as background thats why a fixed width doesnt work for me