# Bleeding image or container off viewpoint whilst still using a column container?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I bleed an image or container (for the background colour) to the edge of the viewport on one side, whilst still using the column grid to reference for the other side and to still house the content within?

I've attached an illustration of my desired outcome. 
[image: A simple sketch concept using the grid]

[This answer is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37985506/enable-bootstrap-column-backgrounds-to-bleed-to-edge-of-viewport) however I need the image to show as much as possible so I don't want to extend it further than necessary.

The markup I am using is similar to bootstraps layout.

```
.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 1140px}
.container--fluid {
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%; 
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}

.col--bleed {
  background: lightgray;
  /* margin-right:calc((100vw - 1140px) / 2) */
}

.col__inner {
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px; 
}
```

Html markup:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-7">
      <div class="col__inner">
        <!-- Content here -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-5 col--bleed">
      <div class="col__inner">
        <!-- Content here -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Heres an example of the markup I will be using in codepen.](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rQMqdd?editors=1100#0)

Comment: Please include your code in the question itself, rather than linking to an off-site code sandbox. Otherwise your question risks being closed as lacking a [mcve].

Comment: @TylerH Sorry, edited the question to include the relevant code snippets.

Comment: Thanks; can you please add some images? You can use placeholder ones of similar size if you don't want to share the specific images you are using in production. That way we can actually view a 'reproduction' rather than just the code. For visual problems like this, that repro is often crucial. Once that's added I will do what I can to get this question reopened.

Comment: @TylerH Hope this is ok to continue with now?

Comment: Much better; I would suggest you include the whole CodePen code here in the question, though.

Comment: @TylerH Thanks, I've added the important bits of code to do with the layout now.

Comment: Look at the key/lock image on https://www.passwordslug.com/ -- when you resize the window this image bleeds off the right edge of the screen. If this is the effect you're after, then you can use this as your starting point.